# PDO code is not entering data to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm using php PDO to post data to an mysql database.

My image loads and is saved to the targeted folder.

When I test the site, everything functions correctly **except no data is entered into the database**.

Code:

```
if( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['description'],$_POST['weblink']) ) {     
           $file = "adimages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posted_ad_img (title, file, link, description, NOW()) VALUES (:title, :image_file_path, :link, :description, :date_post)");
        $stmt -> bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':image_file_path', $file);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':link', $_POST['weblink']);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':date_post', $date);
        // Execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Record was added!.</div>";
    }else{
        die("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Unable to update record!</div>");
    }
       }
    }
```

Why is the data not showing when I go into the phpadmin to view the tables?

Comment: always turn on error reporting and `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); `

Comment: Do you actually have a column called `NOW()`?!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe it's a futuristic naming convention :D

Comment: @Rizier123 FIIK - FIIK if OP is reading comments.

Comment: Even if there were a column named NOW() it would have to be surrounded in backticks for the query to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$dsn` before  `$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);` as

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$DATABASE.';host='.$SERVER.'';
```

You can also replace bindParam with array inside execute.

So the whole code will be as:

```
if( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['description'],$_POST['weblink']) ) {     
           $file = "adimages/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        **$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$DATABASE.';host='.$SERVER.'';**
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posted_ad_img (title, file, link, description, NOW()) VALUES (:title, :image_file_path, :link, :description, :date_post)");

        // Execute the query
    if($stmt->execute(array("title"=>$_POST['title'],"image_file_path"=>$file,"description"=>$_POST['description'],"link"=>$_POST['weblink'],"date_post"=>$date))){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Record was added!.</div>";
    }else{
        die("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Unable to update record!</div>");
    }
       }
    }
```

Use following code to check wheater PDO is enabled in your server or not:

```
try {
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$DATABASE.';host='.$SERVER.'';
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I just add the define where you put, everything still goes right on the web page but when I go back to check the database, the data is till not entered. I guess somehow it's not being passed through.

Comment: You need to go php/php.ini file and search PDO and remove the ; sign before it and restart the apache.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, not paying attention to the brackets. I was executing the pdo statement inside of the else instead of moving the code outside of it. Once I did the code executed.